# Create a WYSIWYG Editor Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wysiwyg

I have a task to create a wysiwyg editor as an eclipse plugin. Please suggest me what are the prerequisites for developement in eclipse , I have working editor which is build using HTML and jQuery .

Please provide any document and existing plugin source code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using [Sapphire](http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/)?